Svelte не прогружается и не работает hot reload

svelte-app@1.0.0 start
sirv public --no-clear

  Your application is ready~! 

  - Local:      http://localhost:8080
  - Network:    Add `--host` to expose

────────────────── LOGS ──────────────────

Раньше в лог была инфа подгружаемых файлов, теперь отсутствует/грузит очень долго

при сохранении файла не обновляет лог и сайт

{
  "name": "svelte-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "dev": "rollup -c -w",
    "start": "sirv public --no-clear"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^24.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-terser": "^0.4.0",
    "rollup": "^3.15.0",
    "rollup-plugin-css-only": "^4.3.0",
    "rollup-plugin-livereload": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^7.1.2",
    "svelte": "^3.55.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "sirv-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "svelte-hamburger": "^1.0.1",
    "svelte-transitions": "^1.2.0",
    "uuid": "^11.0.2"
  }
}


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Когда я запускал проект через npm start, лог выглядел вот так:
── LOGS ──
[18:50:15] 200 ─ 8.96ms ─ /
[18:50:15] 200 ─ 1.67ms ─ /build/bundle.js
[18:50:15] 200 ─ 3.33ms ─ /build/bundle.css
[18:50:15] 200 ─ 4.38ms ─ /global.css
[18:50:15] 200 ─ 6.36ms ─ /photo/photo1.jpg
[18:50:15] 200 ─ 1.07ms ─ /favicon.png
[18:50:42] 200 ─ 2.23ms ─ /build/bundle.js.map
[18:54:01] 200 ─ 1.40ms ─ /build/bundle.js.map
[19:05:52] 200 ─ 4.66ms ─ /build/bundle.js.map
[19:06:30] 200 ─ 1.90ms ─ /build/bundle.js.map
Сейчас он выглядит иначе:
── LOGS ──
[12:49:20] 200 ─ 2.8ms ─ /
